# Data frame selection and NA removal

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am working on the data frame called "juul" that can be found in `library(ISwR)`.
How can I re-write the following expression: `selection= juul[juul$sex==2 & juul$tanner>2,]` so that NA is excluded in the criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
selection <- na.omit(juul[juul$sex==2 & juul$tanner>2,])
```

However, this returns a dataframe with `0` observations. When looking at the result of:

```
selection <- juul[juul$sex==2 & juul$tanner>2,]
```

you can see why. The variable `juul$testvol` has only NA's for this subset. Using `na.omit` will therefore exclude all the observations from this subset. You can prevent that by excluding the `juul$testvol` from the subset with:

```
selection <- na.omit(juul[juul$sex==2 & juul$tanner>2,c(1:5)])
```

or

```
selection <- na.omit(juul[juul$sex==2 & juul$tanner>2,-6])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I see what you are getting at, but I don't understand why your expression returns as 0 observations and 6 varibles in RStudio. I have checked that there are sex=2 with tanner>2 in juul. What am I missing?